# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having 3 Buttons and a Gallery.In my gallery I have got 3 ImageAdapters one for the click of each Button and I am setting a thumbnail image URL which has to be fetched and loaded to those ImageAdapters and I am using AsyncTask for this.

Code:

```
 class AddImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
         try {
         for (String url : PhotoURLS) {
         String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") +
         1,url.length());
         filename = "" + filename;
         String thumburl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
         imageAdapter.addItem(LoadThumbnailFromURL(thumburl+ filename));
         publishProgress();
         }

         for (String url : AudioThumbURLS) {
         String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") +
         1,url.length());
         filename = "" + filename;
         String thumburl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
         imageAdapter1.addItem(LoadThumbnailFromURL(thumburl+ filename));
         publishProgress();
         }
         for (String url : VideoThumbURLS) {
         String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") +
         1,url.length());
         filename = "" + filename;
         String thumburl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
         imageAdapter2.addItem(LoadThumbnailFromURL(thumburl+ filename));
         publishProgress();
         }

         } catch (Exception ae) {
         ae.printStackTrace();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error found in the application",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        imageAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        imageAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    }
}
```

And my LoadThumbnailFromURL method is:

```
   private Drawable LoadThumbnailFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        boolean isImage = contentType.startsWith("");
        if (isImage) {
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(
                    entity);
            InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } else {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.icon);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
            return d;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    return null;
}
```

The application starts up fine but after sometime throws Error as:

> 01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   01-21 15:16:23.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8292):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

What could be the possible reason for this and how do I solve it?

Comment: You could try to call notifyDataSetChanged() only on the updated adapter and see if that is the problem..

Comment: You mean to say that I need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: nope, I mean to pass onPostExecute() method an integer or something to know which adapter was updated and update only that specific adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance that you are catching an exception but getting another exception inside of your catch{}?  Since it is on a different (non-UI) thread, don't try to use Toast to notify yourself of the error.